Crewai - Can I use a Custom embedder in the crewai_tools?
I am trying to use the the crewai_tools, the RAG tools in particular. Lets take the DirectorySearchTool() in this case.
How do I use a custom embedder provider? The only options that embed chain have are from the following list. 'openai', 'gpt4all', 'huggingface', 'vertexai', 'azure_openai', 'google', 'mistralai', 'nvidia' Embedding models for which I need API keys.
directory_search_tool = DirectorySearchTool(
    config=dict(
        llm=dict(
            provider="ollama", # Options include ollama, google, anthropic, llama2, and more
            config=dict(
                model="llama2",
                # Additional configurations here
            ),
        ),
        embedder=dict(
            provider="google", # or openai, ollama, ...
            config=dict(
                model="models/embedding-001",
        ),
    )
)

I know that CrewAI uses embedchain module for RAG operations and the default provider is set to openai. And to use openai embedding model one needs to set OPENAI_API_KEY as environment variable.
But the situation is that the LLMs that I am using is from the from my Company's/Organization's langchain.openai import ChatOpenAI module and I don't need to set API keys and stuff for using the LLMs.  Something like this:
llm = ChatOpenAI(proxy_model_name='gpt-4-32k')

which is of type: gen_ai_hub.proxy.langchain.openai.ChatOpenAI
Question: How do I use a custom embedder provider? Is there a provider called custom or anything that i can use in my case?
I'm not really sure what to try. Any ideas would be helpful

I've used hugging face as provider and compatable embedder based on the embedding dimension and max tokens.
Below is the embedder dict config, which worked for me.
embedder=dict(
                provider="huggingface", # or google, openai, anthropic, 
 llama2.. 
                config=dict(
                    model="izhx/udever-bloom-1b1", 
                ),
            ),


output :
Inserted batches to chromadb. Accuracy of the output was not so great though.
